# Sort dataframe by multiple columns text and numeric while ignoring case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, case-insensitive

How can I sort a Pandas dataframe with text and numeric columns while ignoring the case?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('aabbCC'),
        'B':[2,1,2,1,10,1]
})
```

Based on this answer [Sort dataframe by multiple columns while ignoring case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678636/sort-dataframe-by-multiple-columns-while-ignoring-case/72446995)

```
df.sort_values(by=[ 'A', 'B'], inplace=True, key=lambda x: x.str.lower())
```

I get an error

```
builtins.AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

How do I have to modify the key function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if-else` statement with lowercase for non numeric column:

```
f = lambda x: x if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.str.lower()
df.sort_values(by=[ 'A', 'B'], inplace=True, key=f)
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df.assign(A=df['A'].str.lower()).sort_values(by=[ 'A', 'B']).index]
```

Comment: Your `f` function for `key` (using the subdtype idea) is fantastic.